Incomprehensible protocol overhead present in Table 5-10 of USB 2.0 Standard
The USB 2.0 Standard features a table (table 5-10) where high-speed bulk transaction limits are computed.
The table cites a "Protocol overhead" of 55 bytes, computed as follows.

(3x4 SYNC bytes, 3 PID bytes, 2 EP/ADDR+CRC bytes,
2 CRC16, and a 3x(1+11) byte interpacket delay (EOP, etc.))

What troubles me is the interpacket delay, which I unpacked as follows:

EOP: 8 bits for each package (section 7.1.13.2.2)
Two packets sent in a row by the host (TOKEN OUT + DATAx): 88 bits of interpacket delay (section 7.1.18.2)
(at least) 8 bits of interpacket delay the device must wait before responding ACK (section 7.1.18.2)
(at least) 8 bits of interpacket delay the host must wait before sending the next TOKEN OUT (section 7.1.18.2)

So I justified the 3 EOP bytes + 11 interpacket delay bytes + (at least) 2 interpacket delay bytes.
I don't get where the other 20 bytes come from: it seems they are considered the same as the host sending two packets in a row, but that section does not mandate so high interpacket delay between two packets if the host is not sending two packets in a row.
I get that those 20 bytes can be justified with the phrase "at least", but the table computes the maximum number of bulk transactions in a microframe, so why considering more interpacket delay than necessary?
Thanks.
UPDATE: it seems like the very same protocol overhead is cited in the equations in section 5.11.3, which may be more used than the tables to implement host controller drivers. The confusion still remains: table 7-13 states:
Inter-packet Delay (for high-speed) for packets traveling in same direction: min 88 bit times
Inter-packet Delay (for high-speed) for packets traveling in opposite direction: min 8 bit times.
In an IN transaction with exchange of data only between the host ACK and the next host TOKEN IN there are two packets traveling in the same direction, while if the device replies with a NAK, no packets are traveling in the same direction (assuming that the time between the TOKEN IN and the next TOKEN IN from the host is greater than 88 bit times).
Moreover, why use the minimum host interpacket delay (88 bit times) and not the maximum (192 bit times) in such formulas since they are meant for computing the worst case and they don't even take into account the device max computation time before a response (192 bit times)?

That table is, if not officially, then at least effectively, informative and non-normative in nature. I would submit a bug report and move on.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica So I can safely ignore it. Where should I submit a bug report?

So in the end, the interpacket delay is 8 bit times and not 88? 88 is just for hosts sending two packets in a row in the same transaction, right?
